# Python + Flask: When I choose file image. It not working and not showing on web app

Tags: python, image, tensorflow, flask, keras

The following code gives the error **UnboundLocalError: local variable 'predictions' referenced before assignment**

***Edit:** I add prediction = "" It not error! But when I choose file image. It not working and not showing on web app. What should I do?*

## app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.applications.mobilenet_v2 import preprocess_input
from tensorflow.keras.models import model_from_json
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from io import BytesIO
from keras.models import load_model

model = None
app = Flask(__name__)

model = load_model('model.h5')

def process_image(image):
    image = Image.open(BytesIO(image))
    if image.mode != "RGB":
        image = image.convert("RGB")
    image = image.resize((224, 224))
    image = img_to_array(image)
    image = preprocess_input(image)
    image = np.expand_dims(image, axis = 0)
    return image

@app.route("/submit", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def get_output():
        if request.method == "POST":
            if request.files:
                try:
                    image = request.files["image"].read()
                    image = process_image(image)
                    out = model.predict(image)
                    if np.round(out[0][1], 2) > np.round(out[0][0], 2):
                        predictions = "Normal have an accuracy of " + str(np.round(out[0][1]*100, 2)) + "%"
                    else:
                        predictions = "Pneumonia have an accuracy of " + str(np.round(out[0][0]*100, 2)) + "%"
                except:
                    redirect('/submit')
        return render_template("Analysis.html", predictions = predictions)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug = True, threaded = False)
```

I'm having troubles with flask. I get this error

What can I do?

## html

```
<section class="upload">
    <form id = "upload" action="/submit" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <center style="margin-top: 1rem;">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="file" id="image" name="image" onchange="loadFile(event)">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" id ="predict" class="btn btn-primary" style="display: none; margin-top: 1rem;">Predict Image</button>
        </div>
    </center>
    </form>
</section>

<center style="margin-top: 1rem;">
<section class="Predictions">
    <div>
    {% if predictions %}
        <div class="img-preview">
        <p><img id="output" style="width: 100%; height: 480px;" /></p>
        </div>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" style="font-size: 20px; margin-top: 1rem;">{{predictions}}</button>
    {% endif %}
    </div>
</section>

<script>
window.onload = function() {
    let profileImage = localStorage.getItem("profileImageData");
    if (profileImage !== null) {
                                           
        document.getElementById("output").src = profileImage
    }
}

const loadFile = function(event) {
    document.getElementById('predict').style.display = 'block'                              
    let image = document.getElementById('output');
    image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
};
                         document.getElementById("image").addEventListener('change', function() {
    var file = this.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = function () {                                   
        localStorage.setItem("profileImageData", reader.result);
    };
} );
</script>
</center>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Well my guess would be that since you create the variable predictions only inside of the two if commands, python tells you, that you can't return it, since it's not 100% sure the variable gets created.

```
def get_output():
    if request.method == "POST":
        predictions = ""
        if request.files:
            try:
                image = request.files["image"].read()
                image = process_image(image)
                out = model.predict(image)
                if np.round(out[0][1], 2) > np.round(out[0][0], 2):
                    predictions = "Normal have an accuracy of " + str(np.round(out[0][1]*100, 2)) + "%"
                else:
                    predictions = "Pneumonia have an accuracy of " + str(np.round(out[0][0]*100, 2)) + "%"
            except:
                redirect('/submit')
    return render_template("Analysis.html", predictions = predictions)
```

adding the predictions = "" makes sure the variable exists!

i have experienced this many times... for me it worked out!

Comment: It not error! but not working and not showing on web app. How can I fix this?

Comment: Well from what I can see here, you are returning a render_template. I'm not sure what it should return but you can check that by printing out the return like `print(get_output())` or save the return of the method whenever you call it in your code and then cross-check it's validity. 
Maybe the method isn't returning the correct code.